Inner products induced by inner product and multiplication of vectors, e.g. $f(A,B) = tr(A^TB)-tr(A)tr(B)$ as an inner product?
It just came to my attention that both the expected value $\mathbb{E}(XY)$ and the covariance $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ can be understood as scalar products.
This is a consequence of the linearity of the expected value and the commutation of the product of random variables.
With $$E(X^2) \geq E(X)^2 \geq 0$$ (by  Jensen's inequality or from the positive semi-definity of the variance) and $$\mathbb{E}(X) = 0 \iff X=0 \quad (a.s)$$ we have the necessary properties of a inner product.
For the Covariance we can derive the same properties:
$$\text{Cov}(X,Y) := \mathbb{E}(XY) - \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$$
Linearity follows from linearity of the expected value,
symmetry by symmetry of expected value and multiplication of real numbers.
It is positive semi-definite, as covariance is never negative and only vanishes if X is constant (we have to identify constant functions with zero).

What is needed to get another inner product, if we already have one?
Is a multiplication of vectors enough?
Is this multiplication algebraicly a ring with 1?

It doesn't seem possible for the "standard" vector spaces,$K^n$, however for functions this seems possible.
I believe it should also work for matrices, which can be multiplied.
Starting with the Frobenius product $tr(A^T B)$ as the inner product of matrices, I hope to find another inner product;

Is $$f(A,B) = -tr(A^TB)+tr(A)tr(B)$$ a scalar product, as I believe?

I will restrict myself in analogy to probabilites to positive semi-definite quadratic matrices ($\implies tr(A)\geq0$).
This can maybe be used for matrix and density calculus in quantum mechanics where probabilies are of course very important.
Its linear and symmetric, as the trace is linear and symmetric.
As always the positve semi-definity is the hardest to check.
The inequalities

$tr(A^TB)\geq0$
$tr(A^TB) \leq tr(A^T)tr(B)$

follow from $tr(A^2)  =\sum_i\lambda_i^2 \leq (\sum_i\lambda_i)^2 = tr(A)^2$ and applying Cauchy Schwarz inequality of the matrix scalar product.
From this it is clear that $f$ is positive semi-definite, with equality only for $A=0$, because if we take $A$ to be a positive semi-definite matrices, all diagoal entries have to vanish, if the trace has to vanish.
Please let me know, if me calculations for this new matrix inner product are correct and if  you know the answer or good references for my questions, feel free to answer!
The restriction to positive definite matrices is necessary, otherwise I can't use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality to show the semi-positivity of the new inner product, isn't it?
The sign difference in $f$ and $Cov$ arises from $E(X^2)\geq E(X)^2$ and $tr(A^2)\leq tr(A)^2$.
Thank you!

$f(A,B)=\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)-\operatorname{tr}(A)\operatorname{tr}(B)$ is not an inner product. E.g. when $f(I_2,I_2)=-2<0$.

try $f(A,B) = tr(A^TB)- \frac{1}{n} tr(A)tr(B)$   with matrices of size $n$

on line 4 you wrote  $E(X^2) \geq E(X^2) \geq 0$ which does not make sense stating so I think you meant to write $E(X^2) \geq E(X)^2 \geq 0$..  You later assert $tr(A^2)=tr(A)^2$ which is false, in fact for (real symmetric) psd $A$, $tr(A^2)\leq tr(A)^2$ will be strict outside of special cases.  I think you are not understanding the role of averaging here.

@user1551, I should have noted that by the second inequality, I'm guessing a sign flip may fix this based on this inequality. If this is really true, any idea where the evidence between $f$ and $Cov$ comes from

@WillJagy, this seems the fix the problem above, but I don't know if this holds generally

@user8675309, fixed the  noted equations; what do you mean by "psd" and "averaging"?

You might want to read more about the Killing form  : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form

@Will Jagy Hi ! Following your comment, I found this reference where it seems that it is an inner product when restricted to traceless matrices. There are other references in the framework of Killing forms using Lie algebras I am not familar with...

@JeanMarie   Thank you, that is very nice. I remembered  the expression from somewhere, years and years ago.

@Will Jagy Yes, this bilinear form appears from time to time. Here is for example another SE question about it.
